# Killing an infinitely-looping threaded application

Tags: python, signals

Consider a hypothetical threaded Python application that runs each thread in an infinite loop:

```
import signal                                                          
import sys 
import threading
import time

class CallSomebody (threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self, target, *args):
                self._target = target
                self._args = args
                threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        def run (self):
                self._target(*self._args)

def call (who):
        while True:
                print "Who you gonna call? %s" % (str(who))



def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)



a=CallSomebody(call, 'Ghostbusters!')
a.daemon=True

b=CallSomebody(call, 'The Exorcist!')
b.daemon=True

a.start()
b.start()

a.join()
b.join()
```

When running the application, sending SIGINT by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> does not stop the application. I tried removing the `daemon` statements but that did not help. What fundamental idea am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `join` a thread the active thread blocks until the joined thread returns.  Yours never do.  You won't want to join them in this way.

Generally, background threads that are daemon threads and that perform infinite loops should be marked daemon, never joined, and then allowed to expire when your main thread does so.  If you happened to be using `wx` for example, you'd make your call to `AppInstance.MainLoop()` after starting the daemonic threads, then when your Frame or whatever other top level instances you had were closed, the program execution would be concluded, and the daemons would be addressed appropriately.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not using `wx` or any other graphics packages at this point, just learning.

Comment: @dotancohen - No worries, and you're welcome.  You could throw in a simple `time.sleep(5)` to show that for several seconds your background threads ran, then let the normal program execution complete.